# Speedup execution of a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, iptables

I have this bash script that loads a large file of iptables rules. All these iptable rules are to block all USA ip addresses. The size of this file is approximately 9MB. When I tried to execute it, it took like 40 Mins to execute.

Is there a way to speedup the execution of this script:

```
# head -n 4 iptables_block_usa.sh 

iptables -A INPUT -s 216.187.112.96/27 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 216.187.112.128/27 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 216.187.112.160/31 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 216.187.112.163/32 -j DROP

......
```

Comment: I think there is no magic. IMHO The only thing you can do is refine the source IP list, larger masks = less lines of code. I notice some /32...

Answer (score 4):

iptables has limitations due to its conception. When *iptables* alters rules, here's what's really happens:

- *iptables* asks kernel the *whole* ruleset
- *iptables* changes (in userspace) the ruleset, typically to add *one* entry
- *iptables* gives back to the kernel the *whole* ruleset

So you must avoid this to happen, because when you're adding one rule to a ruleset of 100000 rules, there's a lot of wasted CPU.

Also, since your rules are written linearly, every time a packet (possibly a packet in NEW state if it's using stateful rules to help about this) is not in this list, *all* rules are traversed to figure out none will match and accept it. So your packet lookup is proportional to the size of the list which is not good.

What to not do:

- Don't attempt to run multiple `iptables` in parallel, there's no kernel locking done about it and you will end up missing rules. Using `iptables --wait` does (userspace) locking, but then it won't be parallel anymore.

You could do instead any of these below to solve your problem:

- use [`iptables-restore`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-restore.8) to load the whole ruleset in one shot.

  Either run once your bash script (and wait) and dump the final result with `iptables-save`, ready to be reused with `iptables-restore`, or edit using *sed* etc your script to have a ready file for `iptables-restore` format. If it's the default filter table, it should have a format similar to this one:

  ```
  *filter
  :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
  :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
  :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
  -A INPUT -s 216.187.112.96/27 -j DROP
  -A INPUT -s 216.187.112.128/27 -j DROP
  -A INPUT -s 216.187.112.160/31 -j DROP
  -A INPUT -s 216.187.112.163/32 -j DROP
  [...]
  -A INPUT -s 192.0.2.0/24 -j DROP
  COMMIT
  ```
- Or else, don't use directly *iptables* to load lists of addresses, use its companion [*ipset*](http://ipset.netfilter.org/) which is optimized to handle this, by using hash tables and only pushing to kernel the entry to add, not asking its list first like does iptables:

  > If you want to
  >
  > - store multiple IP addresses or port numbers and match against the collection by iptables at one swoop;
  > - dynamically update iptables rules against IP addresses or ports **without performance penalty**;
  > - express complex IP address and ports based rulesets with one single iptables rule and benefit from the speed of IP sets
  >
  > then ipset may be the proper tool for you.

  You must define the maximum number of elements (which defaults to "only" 65536). The hash size is resized dynamically by ipset so shouldn't be needed (or consider adding `hashsize 65536` at least). For your simple case (only source IP networks) you'd do something like this:

  ```
  ipset create usa_ips hash:net maxelem 300000 hashsize 65536
  ```

  And now you'll loop over your list using `ipset`. The list could be a file `usa_ips.txt` like this:

  ```
  216.187.112.96/27
  216.187.112.128/27
  216.187.112.160/31
  216.187.112.163/32
  [...]
  ```

  This should then take perhaps 10mn in a loop like this:

  ```
  while read net; do
      ipset add usa_ips $net
  done < usa_ips.txt
  ```

  At the end or before the end you can see how big got the list with for example:

  ```
  # ipset -t list usa_ips
  Name: usa_ips
  Type: hash:net
  Revision: 6
  Header: family inet hashsize 65536 maxelem 300000
  Size in memory: 3847384
  References: 0
  Number of entries: 131076
  ```

  And now you can drop everything matching this list with this single *iptables* rule:

  ```
  iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set usa_ips src -j DROP
  ```

  Which will set the *References* entry above to 1, since iptables is using it.
- The current set made above can be saved and reloaded with `ipset save usa_ips > ipset_usa_ips.txt` and `ipset restore usa_ips < ipset_usa_ips.txt`. When you see the output format, you'll know you can also prepare a one-shot file for it like above, which is way faster: **takes < 1s to load ~130000 entries**. The format is like this:

  UPDATE: actually you'd get an error because the set is now in use, that's why there's a `swap` command available in *ipset*. You have to load the list to an alternate set and swap it with the previous set.

  ```
  create usa_ips_new hash:net family inet hashsize 65536 maxelem 300000
  add usa_ips_new 216.187.112.96/27
  add usa_ips_new 216.187.112.128/27
  add usa_ips_new 216.187.112.160/31
  add usa_ips_new 216.187.112.163/32
  [...]
  ```

  And it can replace the previously created set with:

  ```
  # ipset restore < usa_ips_new.txt
  # ipset swap usa_ips usa_ips_new
  # ipset destroy usa_ips_new
  ```
- switch to *nftables* or at least to the iptables-over-nftables API (which is default on Debian 10 and RHEL 8/CentOS 8)

  *nftables* has been made to address many mistakes done with *iptables*. When adding a rule, only this delta is transmitted to the kernel: it won't require asking the whole ruleset/edit/send back done by *iptables*. The iptables-over-nftables compatibility layer is doing the same, since it's implemented with nftables (and a compatibility layer mainly for iptables' special matches and targets, *ipset* among them, which can't be translated).

  I will stop here and leave to you the exercise. Just know that recent *nftables* used on a recent kernel, has [native sets support](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Sets), which when used with `flags interval` (and possibly `auto-merge` to avoid duplicates) can completely replace the use of *ipset* for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple sources separated by `,`

see [iptables(8)](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html)

> [!] -s, --source address[/mask]**[,...]**
> Source specification. Address can be either a network name, a hostname, a network IP address (with /mask), or a plain IP address. Hostnames will be resolved once only, before the rule is submitted to the kernel. Please note that specifying any name to be resolved with a remote query such as DNS is a really bad idea. The mask can be either an ipv4 network mask (for iptables) or a plain number, specifying the number of 1's at the left side of the network mask. Thus, an iptables mask of 24 is equivalent to 255.255.255.0. A "!" argument before the address specification inverts the sense of the address. The flag --src is an alias for this option. Multiple addresses can be specified, but this will expand to multiple rules (when adding with -A), or will cause multiple rules to be deleted (with -D).

Then You're limited by bash commandline max length which can differ by OS. To find Your limit run

`getconf ARG_MAX`

Doing this will save You executing iptables command many times.

The example from the question will be:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 216.187.112.96/27,216.187.112.128/27,216.187.112.160/31,216.187.112.163/32 -j DROP
```

To make it more readable You should be able to split lines like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s\
  216.187.112.96/27,\
  216.187.112.128/27,\
  216.187.112.160/31,\
  216.187.112.163/32 \
  -j DROP
```

Let's do the math:

- Your file has 9MB. Lines are about 48B that is approx `9 * 1024^2 / 48 ≈ between 190000 and 200000` lines (1 line = 1 invocation of iptables).
- On Ubuntu there's ARG_MAX 2097152. `9 * 1024^2 / 2097152 ≈ 5` lines